# add users to custom audience says schema is not provided - fb ads api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

When I try to hit the custom audience endpoint to add users, I think I provide the correct parameters according to the docs, but it says that I did not provide the schema attribute to payload.

```
payload: { schema: EMAIL_SHA256, data: [<my_email_hashed>, <someones_email_hashed>] }
```

Error message: `"(#100) Missing schema attribute in payloads"`

Does something of mine not look right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! In the Graph Explorer, there must be "-s around EMAIL_SHA256, and around each hashed email in the list. Similar quote carefulness is necessary when doing this from code.

Comment: Basically, structure your JSON properly

Comment: Ya, which didn't immediately pop out to me because the error was about a missing key `schema` which did in fact exist while the problem really lay in the values.